# Not possible to install android wear app with body_sensors permission via adb or on Google Play

Tags: android, google-play, adb, wear-os

The android.permission.BODY_SENSORS was introduced in Android KitKat W API 20. There should be no reason why wear apps cannot use and be published with this permission. However there is a problem that apps installed over adb and via google play don't recognise the BODY_SENSORS permission and so the wear app is not installed on the watch automatically as it should.

I have the BODY_SENSORS permission declared in both the mobile and wear manifests.

Logcat shows that the package manager isn't happy with the permission and the wear app is then not installed:

```
D/PackageManager﹕ New package installed in
W/PackageManager﹕ Unknown permission android.permission.BODY_SENSORS
```

Removing the permission allows both apps to be installed by just installing the main apk on the mobile.

It is possible to install the wear app directly on the watch with the permission via adb.

This bug seems to stop any wear apps being published through google play that have the BODY_SENSORS permission.

Does any one have a solution to allow publishing?

Comment: Are you using BODY_SENSOR or BODY_SENSORS everywhere? I notice an inconsistency in your question that might be the cause of the problem.

Comment: I have tested this out by adding this permission to a sample, and observed the same problem. I'll see what I can find out about this and if there is a solution ...

Comment: Yes it's the BODY_SENSORS permission. Hope you can find a solution, at the moment i have customers asking for it but i cannot deliver it to them. I was forced to remove the permission to get the wear app deployed automatically.

Comment: Can you post your Manifest files?

Comment: @Murphy i've been discussing this with Wayne Piekarski (who's from the android wear team) over on Google+. Even if i take the DataLayer example "as is" and add the BODY_SENSOR permission to both manifests the problem remains.
Both the wear and mobile app gradle files are using these settings:

compileSdkVersion 20
buildToolsVersion '20'

 defaultConfig {
        minSdkVersion 19
        targetSdkVersion 19
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
 }

Both manifests have the BODY_SENSORS permission added.

Comment: @saml Is it a big wear apk? I noticed it could take long before it gets installed. What's your phone and os version? Could you send me your apk so I can test?

Comment: @Murphy take the datalayer example that comes with the android sdk, 1) build an apk and install on your mobile - it will be deployed automatically on the watch. 2) add the BODY_SENSORS permission to both mobile and wear manifests and then rebuild the apk. Try installing this on the mobile - the wear app will not be deployed and you will get the message in the logcat as mentioned in the question.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar issue and found the solution in the Wear logs:

> E/WearablePkgInstaller﹕ Wearable has a permission
>   "android.permission.BODY_SENSORS" that is not defined in the host
>   application's manifest.

You should use the same permissions on the wear app and mobile app.

I didn't find any info in the official docs, but it makes sense to show these to the user when they install from the Play Store as the Wear app install is silent.

I also believe the application id (package name) need to be the same for both mobile and wear apps.

Comment: that's not the solution, both manifests have the permission already.

Comment: @saml I had the same issue and this fixed it for my app using body sensors: my packaged wear app is now installed automatically when I install the mobile app. Did you check if you use the same package name as I mentioned?

Comment: the package name is the same. With out BODY_SENSORS permission - install on mobile and wear app is automatically deployed, With BODY_SENSOR permission (Both manifests) - install on mobile and wear app is NOT automatically deployed. The gradle settings are  compileSdkVersion 20 buildToolsVersion '20' defaultConfig { minSdkVersion 19 targetSdkVersion 19 versionCode 1 versionName "1.0" }